# Uso do metodo split

Tags: java, lista

Bom dia pessoal, desculpem minha ignorância pela dúvida simples. Vou direto ao ponto.

Tenho uma list de alertas

```
List<Alertas> alertas;
```

Essa lista existem varias mensagens enviadas a alguns usuários, nela tenho os seguintes métodos que posso usar:

```
getUsers_receive;
getMsg;
```

Esse é meu banco de dados:
[image: Banco de dados]

A ideia é que somente posso mostrar a mensagem se o usuario da pessoa estiver nos "usrs_receive" então para isso eu preciso varrer a lista que ja tenho de "user_receive" e tentar encontrar o usuário da pessoa.

Todos os usuários ficam separados por virgula, então logo sei que posso usar o Split para fazer isso.

Minha dificuldade se encontra em:
Separar os user_received com o split e apos isso localizar se em algum desses usuários eu encontro determinado usuário.

Atualmente o que tenho é apenas isso:

```
for (Alertas a : lista_alertas) {
    String[] usrs = a.getUsers_receive().split(",");
}
```

Comment: Vinicius, você está usando Java versão 8? Pergunto isso pois existem uns truques legais que podem ser feitos com `Stream`. Caso contrário você está no caminho correto. Você pode tentar varrer o array `usrs` e ver se alguma das posições contém o usuário atual. Alternativamente, se você for fazer a mesma coisa várias vezes para diferentes usuários talvez valha a pena construir um `HashSet` com o conteúdo de `usrs`, assim você pode utilizar o método `contains` que tem performance constante amortizada (é mais rápido do que varrer o array).

Comment: Estou usando a 8 sim @AnthonyAccioly, vou pesquisar sobre Stream. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer algo mais simples. Use o método `String.IndexOf`, ele retorna a posição da `String` desejada em outra `String`, e quando não encontra retorna -1.

```
Boolean existe = (a.getUsers_receive().IndexOf(usuario) >= 0);
```

Fonte: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
 for (Alertas a : lista_alertas) {
        String[] usrs = a.getUsers_receive().split(",");
        for (String usr : usrs) {
            if (usr.equals("vinicius.candido")) {
                System.out.println(a.getMsg());
            }

        }
    }
```

não sei se é a forma correta porém deu certo rsrsrs

Answer (score 2):

Solução alternativa usando streams do Java 8:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",");
alertas.stream()
    .filter(a -> p.splitAsStream(a.getUsers_receive()).anyMatch("vinicius.candido"::equals))
    .map(Alertas::getMsg)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

A ideia é quebrar a `String` em uma `Stream` utilizando a classe `Pattern`. O código verifica então se esse alerta contém uma entrada para o usuário em questão. Se sim o código extrai e imprime a mensagem.

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - Stream: Filter on children, return the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38973410/664577)